# Designing resource access: Final enums vs static members of extendable classes

Tags: java, enums, resourcedictionary

I am trying to design a framework for loading resources. So I have two options

1. *Approach 1*
   **Underlying structure:** An `interface` with a simple `abstract class` implementation and more specific `extend`s.
   **Access:** static final members of class initialized to the class.
2. *Approach 2*
   **Underlying structure:** A specific `enum` from the get go, implementing all interface methods: no leveraging partial implementations of abstract classes.
   **Access:** as enum entries

While approach 1 is a lot more flexible and reusable, I like the way enums provide a clean usable list, ready to use as opposed to `static final`s with scope for `Class.instance.instance.instance. ...`

Is there a standard way to do this? Is there a better way to do this?

---

Though not strictly needed here's the code

**Approach 1**

Interface `LoadableResource<T>`

```java
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Queue;

public interface LoadableResource<T> {
    Queue<Exception> exceptionQueue=new ArrayDeque<>();    
    boolean load();//Load the resource and return status
    boolean isLoaded() ;    
    T getResource();
    void onLoadFail();
    void onLoadSuccess();
    void onException(Exception ex);
    Queue<Exception> getExcpetions();
}
```

Abstract `SimpleLoadableResource<T>`

```java
import java.util.Queue;

public abstract   class SimpleLoadableResource<T> implements LoadableResource<T> {

    private boolean FLAG_LOADED = false;
    private T resource;

    @Override
    public boolean isLoaded() {
        return FLAG_LOADED;
    }
    @Override
    public T getResource() {
        return resource;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadFail() {}
    @Override
    public void onLoadSuccess() {}
    @Override
    public void onException(Exception ex) {exceptionQueue.add(ex); }
    @Override
    public Queue<Exception> getExcpetions() { return exceptionQueue; }

    protected void setLoaded(boolean FLAG_LOADED) {
        this.FLAG_LOADED = FLAG_LOADED;
    }

    public abstract T loader() throws Exception;

    @Override
    public boolean load() {
        try {
            resource=loader();

        } catch (Exception e) { onException(e);  }

        if (isLoaded())
            onLoadSuccess();
        else
            onLoadFail();

        return isLoaded();
    }
}
```

Specific `SimpleLoadableImage`

```java
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;

public class SimpleLoadableImage extends  SimpleLoadableResource<Image>{

    public static final SimpleLoadableImage LOGO1=new SimpleLoadableImage("1.jpg");
    public static final SimpleLoadableImage LOGO2=new SimpleLoadableImage("2.jpg");

    private final String path;

    public SimpleLoadableImage(String path) {
        this.path = path;
        super.load();
    }

    @Override
    public Image loader() throws Exception {
        var res=ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path));
        setLoaded(true);
        return res;
    }
}
```

---

**Approach 2**

```java
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Queue;

public enum SimpleLoadableImage_Enum {
    LOGO1("1.jpg"),
    LOGO("2.jpg");

    private final String path;
    Queue<Exception> exceptionQueue=new ArrayDeque<>();
    private boolean FLAG_LOADED = false;
    private Image resource;

    private SimpleLoadableImage_Enum(String path){
        this.path=path;
        try {

            resource=ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path));
            FLAG_LOADED=true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            exceptionQueue.add(e);
        }
    }

    public boolean isLoaded() { return FLAG_LOADED;  }
    public Image getResource() {  return resource;  }
    public Queue<Exception> getExcpetions() {  return exceptionQueue;  }
}
```

Comment: Are you really trying to make a framework, or just trying to specify your own finite set of loadable resources in your application?  The first approach is good for the former (except that a field declared in an interface is implicitly static, which may not be what you intended), while the second approach is good for the latter.

Comment: @VGR I wanted to write something general enough that when i switched from pngs to svgs I would't have to write the error checks,status etc again. ......yeah..its not a production scale framework but hobbyist scale implementation.....thought something like android might be avaialble

Comment: I think you’re making it more complicated than it needs to be.  For instance, you don’t need an exception queue;  if an application can’t load an image that was supposed to be bundled with it, the application is broken because it was packaged incorrectly, and the exception should propagate.  Who would want their game to continue if it can’t load its own graphics?  So the constants really just need to load their respective image (though a lazy load might be better).

Comment: @VGR yeah its a bit overkill but its good to have access to any exceptions if they occured..of course they shouldn't. May you plz elaborate on the lazy load..need static members.

Comment: Lazy loading means each value’s Image is null when the value object is created.  The URL where it resides is saved in another private field.  The method which retrieves the Image checks if the Image field is null, and sets it if need be, thus guaranteeing it’s loaded only once, without taking a lot of time initially.  Whether this is a superior strategy will depend on the application;  sometimes it’s better to load everything at the start, sometimes it’s better to save memory by loading resources on demand.

Comment: You are comparing two approaches that are not mutual exclusive. `enum` types can implement interfaces. So you can have an interface, an enumeration of built-in implementations and be extensible by allowing alternative implementations. However, you should follow VGR’s recommendation to simplify the interface. In addition to the already mentioned points, there is no sense in having `onLoadFail()`, `onLoadSuccess()`, or `onException(…)` in the interface, as these methods are only useful for the abstract base class which really calls them. The abstract base class may declare them `protected`.

Comment: @holger thnx but every enum(images, audio etc) would have to reimplement all interface methods as no abstract enum....thats the pro and con that i was trying to ask a better solution for and that is why I enforced the eventLsitening in the interface....overall it seems either of the two approaches are fine

Comment: When you follow the suggestions to remove everything that doesn’t belong there, there are only three methods left. That’s acceptable. Besides that, there still are ways to reduce code duplication in such scenarios, 1) `default` methods, 2) delegation.